# How Does An Beginning Photographer Appear Safe and Serious To A Model?

Tags: models, safety

So, I've decided to take up photography on the side. I'm starting with some simple Urban Exploration and Astrophotography, but I know the projects I want to do will eventually require working with models.

However, given that I am 50 years old with no track record of working with models I've pretty much got all the warning signs of 'GuyWithCamera'.

So what are the things that models would be looking for to see me as a safe and serious amateur? I'm assuming shooting in public locations and encouraging them to bring a friend would go a long ways. But are there other things models look for?

If it helps, my target audience for a model would probably be in the 30-45 year old range. I'm not looking to do nudes or anything along those lines. More ironical themes like a fashion shoot in front of a house with a foreclosure sign or a black wedding dress shoot in an abandoned church.

Comment: Perhaps relevant: https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/97910/9161 and https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/19237/9161

Comment: Note this works both ways : make sure *you* are safe too. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Tell them the exact time and location of the shooting well in advance. Plan the first test shooting with each model in a public area (or close-by) to build up trust, and go to remote places for later shootings.

Provide a written contract that is clear and precise and which should contain a list of intended uses for the photographs.

Provide proof that models are covered by insurance if any accidents happen. Abandonned places are highly risky. Beware, that many insurances won't pay if you have an accident in abandoned places. You could find a professional who assesses if it is safe to enter a given place. However I think it will be very, very hard to find someone doing that if you're not the owner of the place. The professional way is to hire a set designer and build an abandoned place in a studio. This is the only way that you can make the shooting really safe.

While I can understand the thrill, personally I would not enter such abandoned buildings, but be happy with outdoor shootings that have the building as background.

Comment: Also note that "abandoned" buildings can still turn out to have owners and there can be issues with the legal right to shoot and license images if you are not careful.

Comment: I always encourage models of either gender to bring a person with them to the shoot. I won't even do the shoot with a female model without an escort. If you have two models who know each other, they can be each other's escort. I also try to bring an assistant and/or a makeup artist on all shoots so there are at least four people in attendance. I also bought a lightweight portable changing room that I can set up on site which further puts model's minds at ease. That being said, shooting in abandoned locations is a great way to get into serious legal trouble.

Comment: I agree. OP already mentioned in question text that friends of the model are invited so I didn't repeat that in my answer. And yes, of course using abandoned places can cause legal issues if there is an owner. I thought this is obvious to everyone.

Comment: Of course, my point was that I actually require an escort in most cases, not just recommend one. I agree that there are things that should be obvious, but sometimes things that should go without saying are still worth saying. For example, shooting on railroad tracks in the US is nearly always trespass on federal property, but it doesn't stop me from seeing hundreds of "model walking down the tracks" shots in young photographer's portfolios every year.

Comment: @LightBender You're absolutely right.

Comment: @LightBender Railroad rights of way are rarely federal property. They're almost always private property of the railroad that owns them. In most case those rights of way were granted in the 19th century to the owners (or their corporate predecessors) by the federal or a state government that gives the railroad precedence over public rights of way that cross the RR's property. That doesn't lessen the fact that around 400 people each year lose their lives while trespassing on railroad property in the United States.

Comment: @MichaelC You are correct that they are rarely federal property, I misspoke and should have said "nearly always considered federal trespassing." Apologies for the incorrect terminology. My (IANAL) understanding is much like airports (which are also usually privately owned, but regulated by the TSA) trespass on railroad tracks (regulated by the Federal Railroad Administration) is a federal crime. This is in addition to trespass also being illegal in all 50 US states.

Comment: If it's a federal offense, the FRA doesn't mention it in any of their educational/informational materials about the issue. See, for example, [this document](https://railroads.dot.gov/sites/fra.dot.gov/files/2019-11/FRA%20Rail%20Trespassing%20Fact%20Sheet.pdf) in which they mention it is a violation of state laws and provide a link to further documents that include state-by-state information.

Comment: It is against federal statutes to willfully and maliciously trespass upon or enter a railroad train, car, or locomotive with the intent to commit murder or robbery. It's also against federal statute to wreck, derail, or set fire to railroads; to place biological agents or destructive substances on transportation vehicles; to release hazardous materials with reckless disregard for human life; to make unworkable or hazardous any tunnels or other structures used in rail travel or to take other steps to interfere with transportation either to harm passengers or with reckless disregard for safety.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelC that's good to know. For anyone else reading this. Don't take that as permission. It's still illegal to trespass in all 50 states and some have specific additional penalties for doing it on tracks. More importantly, as Michael pointed out, it's incredibly dangerous as well.