# How to choose a SLR camera for Comic-Con？

Tags: camera-recommendation

Please recommend a  Comic-Con SLR camera and lens that can be used to shoot both models/People and small GARAGE KIT,As for the budget, please recommend both professional and intermediate levels.

Comment: The related question had a lot of activity back when it was asked specifically about shooting at cosplay conventions/events: [What can I do to get models to take my small camera more seriously?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/97910/15871)